# Meteor Iron-router onBeforeAction this.next undefined

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've got the following route configuration: https://gist.github.com/chriswessels/76a64c421170095eb871

I'm getting the following error when attempting to load a route:

```
Exception in defer callback: TypeError: undefined is not a function
at manageLoadingIndicator (http://localhost:3000/both/router/routes.js?ef701fada29363a443a214f97988ce96ebaec025:30:10)
at RouteController.runHooks (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?da7f2ac81c3fd9daebf49ce9a6980a54caa1dc17:843:16)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?da7f2ac81c3fd9daebf49ce9a6980a54caa1dc17:2302:14
at Tracker.Computation._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:288:36)
at new Tracker.Computation (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:206:10)
at Object.Tracker.autorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:476:11)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?da7f2ac81c3fd9daebf49ce9a6980a54caa1dc17:2279:12
at Utils.extend._run.withNoStopsAllowed (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?da7f2ac81c3fd9daebf49ce9a6980a54caa1dc17:2248:21)
at Tracker.Computation._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:288:36)
at new Tracker.Computation (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:206:10)
```

It's talking about the following line, which is in a onBeforeAction hook:

```
function manageLoadingIndicator (pause) {
  if (this.ready()) {
    Session.set('loading', false);
    this.next(); // THIS LINE HERE
  } else {
    Session.set('loading', true);
    pause();
  }
}
```

Why is `this.next` undefined? Help please!

Chris

Comment: I'm having the same problem Chris.  I'll let you know if I figure it out.  Please do the same for me. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up different versions of Iron router:

Prior to iron router 1.0, `onBeforeAction` would proceed to action unless `pause` (the first arg to `onBeforeAction` is invoked. There is no `.next()` method.

From 1.0 onwards this has been changed. `pause()` is no longer passed as an argument. This is where the `.next()` method replaces it.

You are evidently running on an old version of iron router, so therefore your hook should look like this:

```
function manageLoadingIndicator (pause) {
  if (this.ready()) {
    Session.set('loading', false);
  } else {
    Session.set('loading', true);
    pause();
  }
}
```

Once you upgrade iron router, you need to change it to this:

```
function manageLoadingIndicator () {
  if (this.ready()) {
    Session.set('loading', false);
    this.next();
  } else {
    Session.set('loading', true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're correct that the iron-router API changed from 1.0 onwards, however there was a period of API flux, where the  pause argument was still passed into the callback function alongside this.next. I believe this was version 0.9.4 (which was when I asked this question). I migrated the router setup to use this.next alone after 1.0 hit. To others: This involves ensuring all of your onBeforeAction hooks call this.next. Pausing a route's execution is opt-out rather than opt-in as it was before.